# Path для MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть `MultiBinding`, который возвращает экземпляр класса, как обратиться к его полю? `Path="ObjectLink"` не отрабатывает, т.к. `Path` в `MultiBinding` отсутствует

```
  <TextBlock Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text">
          <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Path="ObjectLink" Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=m_GetObjectPropertyConverter}" StringFormat=' ({0})'>
              <Binding/>
              <Binding Source="{x:Static DataViewModels:PropertysViewModel.TypeSS}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
  </TextBlock>
```

PS: конвертер `m_GetObjectPropertyConverter` возвращает экземпляр класса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать двойную привязку через `Tag`:

```
<Setter Property="Tag">
  <Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource m_GetObjectPropertyConverter}">
      <Binding/>
      <Binding Source="{x:Static DataViewModels:PropertysViewModel.TypeSS}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Text"
        Value="{Binding Tag.ObjectLink, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: А если, допустим, результат `MultiBinding` поменяет значение `Binding Tag` это отловит?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик: Ага, они будут по идее ловить изменения по цепочке.

Comment: Думаю тогда это мне подойдёт...